# Backspace key to return previous form

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to return to previous form in C# using backspace key.
I am using KeyDown event on form to check for backspace key . but the form is not detecting any key down event.

How can I achieve this?

```
private void History_P_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData.ToString() == "Back")
        MessageBox.Show("Back button pressed");
}
```

where History_P is form name.

Comment: Please do not forget to mark the question as answered if it helped you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable the [`KeyPreview`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx) property on the `Form`.

With this property the key being pressed (all `KeyUp`, `KeyDown`, `KeyPressed` events) will first be caught by the `Form` and is then passed on to the control that is focused at that moment, unless you set the `KeyPressEventArgs.Handled` to `true`.